# updating Rails fixtures during tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I have a functional test in Rails (it's a Redmine plugin) which is causing me problems:

```
fixtures :settings

test 'error is shown on issues#show when issue custom field is not set up' do
  setting = settings(:release_notes)
  setting.value = setting.value.
    update('issue_required_field_id' => 'garbage')
  #setting.save!

  get :show, :id => '1'

  assert_response :success
  assert_select 'div.flash.error',
    :text => I18n.t(:failed_find_issue_custom_field)
end
```

The Setting model has fields `name` and `value`; in this particular setting, the value is a hash which is serialised. One of the keys in this hash is `issue_required_field_id`, which is used to find a particular `IssueCustomField` during the show action. If there is no custom field with this ID (which there shouldn't be, because I've set it to the string 'garbage') then it should render a div.flash.error explaining what's happened.

Unfortunately when `setting.save!` is commented out, the test fails because the Setting doesn't appear to have been updated -- the working value for that setting (as appears in settings.yml) is used, and the 'div.flash.error' doesn't appear. If I uncomment it, this test passes, but others fail because the change isn't rolled back at the end of the test.

Is there a way of modifying a fixture like this so that any changes are rolled back at the end of the test?

Note: `self.use_transactional_fixtures` is definitely set to true in `ActiveSupport::TestCase` (and this test case is an `ActionController::TestCase`, which is a subclass)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out what was going on -- the test was actually behaving transactionally, but Redmine's Setting class has its own cache. Adding `Setting.clear_cache!` to the test's `setup` fixed it.